# Trying to connect firebase to my project but installing error in pyrebase and import pyrebase error

Tags: python, firebase, python-requests, virtualenv, pyrebase

I am trying to use python firebase.google.com and connecting my project to my python file I have installed **pyrebase4** according to docs I am done everything

I have faced many problems like

while importing **pyrebase**  in a python file I got error like
[image]

secondly When trying to install **pyrebase** I am getting error like

```
Installation error with pycryptodome
(and a lots of line with after this )
```

someone from github provide instruction

```
pip install pyrebase4
pip install pyrebase-t
pip install pycryptodome
```

but pycryptodome also successfully installed but Getting error in

```
pip install pyrebase-t
```

with error something like

```
Attempting uninstall: requests
    Found existing installation: requests 2.11.1
    Uninstalling requests-2.11.1:
      Successfully uninstalled requests-2.11.1
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. 
This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
pyrebase4 4.4.3 requires oauth2client>=4.1.2, but you have oauth2client 3.0.0 which is incompatible.       
pyrebase-t 1.0.28 requires requests==2.11.1, but you have requests 2.25.1 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed requests-2.25.1
```

Comment: Again I am showing different error after uninstalling 
pyrebase-t 

something like AttributeError: module 'pyrebase' has no attribute 'initialize_app'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first uninstall `pyrebase`, `pyrebase4`, `pyrebase-t` or `pycryptodome` by running this command

```
pip uninstall pyrebase, pyrebase4, pyrebase-t, pycryptodome
```

then reinstall `pycryptodome` by running the following command

```
pip install pycryptodome
```

after that install `pyrebase4` by running the command below

```
pip install pyrebase4
```

hope this will solve the problem as it solved mine.